# Block a task until a queue is not empty in Rust

Tags: concurrency, rust

I need to dispatch jobs between a set of tasks. The [std::sync::deque](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/deque/) is enough to resolve this problem, but I need to block the task if the queue is empty.

The following code (available in a [GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/ayosec/aee066d5e5a3f38c66b9#file-jobs-rs)) is a working example of how to use `std::sync::deque`:

```
extern crate time;

use std::io::timer::sleep;
use std::sync::deque::{BufferPool, Empty, Abort, Data};
use std::time::Duration;

fn main() {

  let start = time::precise_time_s();
  let pool = BufferPool::new();
  let (worker, stealer) = pool.deque();

  for task_id in range(1i, 5) {
    let sc = stealer.clone();
    spawn(proc() {
      loop {
        let elapse = time::precise_time_s() - start;
        match sc.steal() {
          Empty      => { println!("[{} @ {:#7.4}] No items", task_id, elapse); sleep(Duration::milliseconds(300)) },
          Abort      =>   println!("[{} @ {:#7.4}] ABORT. Retrying.", task_id, elapse),
          Data(item) =>   println!("[{} @ {:#7.4}] Found {}", task_id, elapse, item)
        }
      }
    });
  }

  for item in range(1i, 1000) {
    for n in range(1i, 20) {
      worker.push(item * n);
    }
    sleep(Duration::milliseconds(1000));
  }

}
```

I saw that there is a [std::sync::TaskPool](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.TaskPool.html), but the [current implementation](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/libstd/sync/task_pool.rs#L81-L85) send the job to a task even if the thread is busy with an older job.

My question is: What is the best way to block the task until there is any item in the queue?

Answer (score 4):

On possible solution is using a semaphore:

```
extern crate time;

use std::io::timer::sleep;
use std::sync::deque::{BufferPool, Empty, Abort, Data};
use std::sync::{Semaphore, Arc};
use std::time::Duration;

fn main() {

  let start = time::precise_time_s();
  let pool = BufferPool::new();
  let (worker, stealer) = pool.deque();
  let sem = Arc::new(Semaphore::new(0));

  for task_id in range(1i, 5) {
    let sc = stealer.clone();
    let s = sem.clone();
    spawn(proc() {
      loop {
        let elapse = time::precise_time_s() - start;
        s.acquire();
        match sc.steal() {
          Empty      => {
              println!("[{} @ {:#7.4}] No items", task_id, elapse);
              sleep(Duration::milliseconds(300))
          },
          Abort      =>   {
              println!("[{} @ {:#7.4}] ABORT. Retrying.", task_id, elapse);
              s.release();
          },
          Data(item) =>   println!("[{} @ {:#7.4}] Found {}", task_id, elapse, item)
        }
      }
    });
  }

  for item in range(1i, 1000) {
    for n in range(1i, 20) {
      worker.push(item * n);
      sem.release();
    }
    sleep(Duration::milliseconds(1000));
  }

}
```

As you can see here you release a semaphore resource on every value produced and acquire it before getting a value from the queue. In this case returned value will never be empty but Abort is still possible and you must release the resource because nothing is read but the value is still in queue.

Another possible solution is also using channels that block when there are no values as you want. For performance you will have to benchmark both solutions.

Comment: Thanks you! Finally, I used a global semaphore for all workers, which is `release()` for every job. Code is in https://gist.github.com/ayosec/aee066d5e5a3f38c66b9#file-jobs_semaphore-rs

Comment: @Ayose: you forgot to release a resource on `Abort`. This way you will leave one value for every abort in the queue when the task will block.

Comment: Or just call `steal()` in a loop until you get the data.

Comment: You are right. Thanks for the review! I updated the gist with a fix for this issue, using a `loop` to wrap the `steal()`. The diff is visible in https://gist.github.com/ayosec/aee066d5e5a3f38c66b9/revisions